# How to make this toggle menu with only javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have use this default menu in my blogger template but I have noticed the library used on it affacting the Web speed. So please anyone help me to make this menu without jquery library. Thank you.

```html
<script rel='preload' src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<div class='main-nav-main'>
  <div class='mobile-menu' />
  <div class='ct-wrapper'>
    <span class='slide-menu-toggle'>Menu</span>
    <!-- Main menu -->
    <ul class='sf-menu'>
      <li><a href='/'>Home</a></li>
      <li><a href='/p/sample-page_12.html'>sample page</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>drop down</a>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<script type='text/javascript'>
  //<![CDATA[
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('ul.sf-menu').clone().appendTo('.mobile-menu');
    $('.slide-menu-toggle').on('click', function() {
      $('body').toggleClass('nav-active');
    });

  });
  //]]>
</script>
```

https://bltemplatetest2.blogspot.com/ check this for demo, I couldn't add css because of large size

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Use snack JavaScript  library instead. https://snackjs.com/

Comment: @desbest how would that improve the page speed?

Comment: @EmielZuurbier by not loading the jQuery library obviously. (Well, unless cached already by the browser)

Comment: Please add the necessary CSS for this snippet to actually have the desired effect.

Comment: Jquery minified is 90KB, Snack is 3.4KB. Some ISPs will throttle the download speed of a file if it has been downloading for over a certain amount of seconds, minutes or hours - especially public wifi hotspots and mobile networks (or cellular) doing traffic management to fairly allocate the finite amount of spectrum. Also some ISPs will throttle a website, web page or web page resource (css/js/images/fonts), the more popular it is by their overall customers or a single user if they have been visited by a user over a certain amount of times.

Comment: `<div class='mobile-menu' />` ?? You mean: `<div class='mobile-menu'></div>`. DIV is not in the family of void elements like `<br> <input>` etc.

Comment: @desbest That's quite the difference. But you don't know if the size of the script is the issue. Google Pagespeed scores give you penalties on any script that is render blocking, even if it is small. Besides, Snack gives you more functionalities than this solution requires. A Vanilla JS rewrite solves both the size and / or render blocking issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a remake in pure JavaScript.
Basically what it uses is:

- a small utility function `EL()` to query the DOM for elements
- [.addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead of jQuery `.on()` and `.click()` methods
- [.cloneNode()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode) method to clone elements with the `true` argument
- [.classList.toggle()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) method instead of jQuery's `.toggleClass()`

```js
const EL = (sel, el) => (el || document).querySelector(sel);

const EL_body = EL("body");
const EL_menu_sf = EL(".sf-menu");
const EL_menu_sf_cln = EL_menu_sf.cloneNode(true);
const EL_menu_mobile = EL(".mobile-menu");
const EL_menu_toggle = EL(".slide-menu-toggle");

EL_menu_mobile.append(EL_menu_sf_cln);

EL_menu_toggle.addEventListener("click", () => {
  EL_body.classList.toggle("nav-active");
});
```

```css
.mobile-menu                 { display: none; }
body.nav-active .mobile-menu { display: block; }
```

```html
<div class='main-nav-main'>
  <div class='mobile-menu'></div>
  <div class='ct-wrapper'>
    <span class='slide-menu-toggle'>Menu (click me)</span>
    <!-- Main menu -->
    <ul class='sf-menu'>
      <li><a href='/'>Home</a></li>
      <li><a href='/p/sample-page_12.html'>sample page</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>drop down</a>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

And just to spice your imagination, here's one without JS at all:

```css
#menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  background: #ddd;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

#menu nav {
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  gap: 1em;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.menu-icon {
  position: fixed;
  top: 1em;
  right: 2em;
  font-size: 2em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#menu-toggle:checked~#menu {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}
```

```html
<input id="menu-toggle" type="checkbox" hidden />

<label class="menu-icon" for="menu-toggle" aria-label="Toggle menu">☰</label>

<div id="menu">

  <label class="menu-icon" for="menu-toggle" aria-label="Toggle menu">✖</label>

  <nav>
    <a href="#!">HOME</a>
    <a href="#!">ABOUT</a>
    <a href="#!">PRODUCTS</a>
    <a href="#!">CONTACT</a>
  </nav>

</div>
```